# How to use AND operator in Android DataBase

Tags: android

I used like this but don't know what happend it did'nt show nothing.
SO how can use AND operator in my code as:
database java:

```
public boolean loginstatus(String TABLE_NAME,String COL_3,StringCOL_4,String log,String pss)
{
try {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COL_4+COL_3+" FROM
    "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COL_4+"='"+log+" AND
    "+COL_3+"=,"+pss+"'",null);  

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        db.close();
        Log.d("Record  Already Exists", "Table is:"+TABLE_NAME+"
                ColumnName:"+COL_4);
        return true;//record Exists
    }
```

and this is the activity class code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {

        boolean recordExists = 
          myDb.loginstatus(DatabaseOperation.TABLE_NAME,DatabaseOperation.COL_3,user.getText().toString(),DatabaseOperation.COL_4,us.getText().toString());

        if (recordExists) { }
```

Comment: Did it work before the AND-operator?  And does this work?  ("SELECT " + COL_4 + ", " + COL_3 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_4 + "='" + log + " AND " + COL_3 + "= '" + pss + "'",null);

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing a comma in your query. If you look at `SELECT "+COL_4+COL_3+" FROM` you can see that you just add your column names together.

So if COL_4 is username und COL_3 is email your query will query:

```
SELECT usernameemail FROM ...
```

So you get no results because that column probably won't exist. You also are missing a ' .
Try editing your query like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_4 + "," + COL_3 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE" + COL_4 + " = '" + log + "' AND " + COL_3 + " = '" + pss + "'",null);
```

Comment: it show error as  near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT 12,PASS FROM student_tableWHERE12 = 'CONTACT' AND PASS = '12'

Comment: Then you have a flaw in your sql logic. What exactly are you trying to select from your database? Username and password? I also forgot a space in my answer above and edited it in.

Comment: this workd correctly  Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COL_4+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COL_4+"='"+chek+"'",null); but i want  twor column as ;

Comment: What exactly do you want? Your comment doesn't make sense :)